# Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
  public int getcid(string UserName)
  {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            con.Open();

            int js;

            string query = "select Username from register_tab where Email='" + UserName + "' ";
            sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sqlda.Fill(ds);

            js = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Username"].ToString());

            return (js);
```

[image]

Comment: what is username? string, int, your custom Object?

Comment: Additionally, the *first* thing to fix is your SQL Injection Attack vulnerability. Use parameterized queries, *always*.

Comment: i get user name from email address  when i login .....and add this user name into session

Comment: You are converting username to int, and it may contain some string value

Comment: username is string

Comment: yes help me and share me code for string value

Comment: Read some tutorials "how to query SQL Database with c#". If you want to get only 1 value from your query use SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar(). Basically i don't know what your method should do. What is expected output ? What is input ? What is name of value from database you are trying to get ? What is value of current output ?

Comment: if ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Username"] contains any character insetad of numeric or alphanumeric then C# compiler always throw System.FormatException. In this situation, your DB column value might be a combination of alphanumeric.
Another thing never append .ToString() function on DB Values becasue it throws exception if the result value is null. Always use Convert.ToString() function.

Answer (score 1):

Change your method to this and check it out:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            con.Open();
string js;
string query= "select Username from register_tab where Email= @username";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@username",SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value =  
                                           UserName;

using(SqlDataReader reader= cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        js=  reader["Username"].ToString();
    }
}

con.Close();
return js;
```

Also why do you set your UserName to Email Column in your query?
And why do you use DataSet if you only want to return int?

UPDATE: no need to convert to int.

Comment: md.Parameters.Add("@Email",SqlDbType.NVarchar,20).Value =  
                                           UserName;

Comment: @AliHacter updated to this: cmd.Parameters.Add("@username",SqlDbType.NVarchar,20).Value

Comment: what is your UserName's dataType?

Comment: UserNAme datatype is string

Comment: varchar (50) is data type

Comment: UserName's dataType is varchar(50)

Comment: @AliHacter ok. check my answer now!

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.
Input string was not in a correct format.

Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Source Error:


Line 33:             using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
Line 34:             {
Line 35:                 while (reader.Read())
Line 36:                 {
Line 37:                     js = reader["Username"].ToString();

Comment: what is Username value when you call your method?

Comment: username vaue is    ali

Comment: @AliHacter and what is your Email column's DataType?

Comment: Email column's DataType is also varchar(50)

Comment: i tested the same method on my computer with 'ali' parameter. It works. I dont know what is your problem. Send your updated code. I may help

Comment: sir kindly sent me ur facebook id or emil .....then i sent u complete code

Comment: public partial class LoginUSer : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ali"].ConnectionString;
        SqlCommand com;
        SqlDataAdapter sqlda;
        string str;
        DataTable dt;
        int RowCount;


        public int getcid(string UserName)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            con.Open();
            int js;

Comment: string query = "select Username from register_tab where Email= @username";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value =
                                                       UserName;

Comment: using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    js = reader["Username"].ToString();
                }
            }

            con.Close();
            return js;

        }

Comment: protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string UserName = username.Text.Trim();
            string Password = txtPassword.Text.Trim();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            con.Open();
            str = "Select * from register_tab";
            com = new SqlCommand(str);
            sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(com.CommandText, con);
            dt = new DataTable();
            sqlda.Fill(dt);
            RowCount = dt.Rows.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < RowCount; i++)
            {

Comment: UserName = dt.Rows[i]["Email"].ToString();
                Password = dt.Rows[i]["Password"].ToString();
                if (UserName == username.Text && Password == txtPassword.Text)
                {
                    Session["Email"] = UserName;
                    int cid = getcid(UserName);
                    Session.Add("Username", cid);
                    Response.Redirect("USerHome.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    Label1.Text = "Invalid User Name or Password! Please try again!";

Comment: @AliHacter no, put your code into your question. I cant read it here from comments :/